# string offsets in java and python

Tags: java, python, encoding

I'm a starter python programmer and I used to know a bit java in the past.
I have some text files (in Turkish) and corresponding xml files which contains offset numbers of
the connectives in the text. For example

```
-<Conn> 
    -<Span> 
        <Text>ama</Text> 
        <BeginOffset>281</BeginOffset> 
        <EndOffset>284</EndOffset> 
    </Span> 
</Conn>
```

this says that there is an 'ama' at the 281 offset in the txt file. But when I read this file with python,
'ama' is at the 301. byte or it is the 272. character in the file. As far as I know, java application doesn't mention any encoding while reading txt files. And I tried to read files with unicode, UTF8 etc...
I need to find a way from these offsets to correct positions in the files. my guess, problem is due to Turkish characters (which may takes different numbers of bytes in different encodings) but I coudn't figure it out.
Any suggestion will be very very good for me.
thanks
**Edit:**
I used following code in python3.3:

```
f = open(path, encoding='utf-8')
text = f.read()
text[272:275] # returns 'ama' but it should be text[281:284]
ibbyte = text.encode(encoding='utf-8')
inbytes[292:295] # returns 'ama' but this is also incorrect
```

Comment: Please show the code you're using to open and read the file.

Comment: Bytes are not always equal to characters...

Comment: Another difference can be end-of-line markers.  In Windows they are 2 raw bytes.

Comment: you could try with Turkish encoding f = open(path, encoding='cp857')

Answer (score 0):

as @Gene says it's end-of-line markers. since the java application written in windows, it counts each '\n' as 2 bytes. But python counts them as 1 byte. I count '\n' until the offset number and substract it from the given offset number. 
thank you very much for your insightful comments